# How to get indices from tensor where the scores (values) satisfies a condition after using torch.topk

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch, array-broadcasting

I have a Tensor of shape `mxm` which is basically the similarity or inner product of two tensors. I want to Get all the values which are above 0.5 only. How could I go this? (**`numpy` operations would do too**)

Example:

```
x = torch.randn((9052, 512))
similarities = x @ x.T
scores, indices = torch.topk(similarities, x.shape[0]) # topk == all the values, sorted
```

I have tried

```
mask = torch.ones(scores.size()[0])
mask = 1 - mask.diag()
sim_vec = torch.nonzero((scores >= 0.5)*mask)
```

Gives me a tensor of shape `[39672595, 2]`

I've also tried

```
(scores > 0.5 ).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]
```

It gives me a tensor of shape `[51152826]`

**Expected Result Pseudo Code**:

```
result = []
for i, row in enumerate(scores):
    temp = []
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        if value > 0.5: 
            temp.append(indices[i][j].item())
    result.append(temp)
```

**Update**:

The below code gives the `Upper Triangle` which shows that which element is closest to the other one. Main problem still persists of filtering and getting the index:

```
import pandas as pd
matrix = pd.DataFrame(scores.numpy().astype(np.float32))
upper_tri = matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(matrix.shape),k=1).astype(np.bool))
```

Comment: Why does not just `similarities[similarities > 0.5]` work for you?

Comment: i'm a bit unsure about the format output you need: you want a list (or 1D array) with the elements being the coordinates of values in the original matrix that pass the test? Something like `[[0,3], [0,21], [1,34], [5,44], ...]`?

Comment: @TheExile because it produces a 1-D Tensor of `torch.Size([51152826])`. How and I supposed to make sense of it, I mean which elements are closest to others, in order? Maybe I'm missing some concept?

Comment: @Puff The result I'm looking for is something like: **For each index `i` , get all the values which are closer than `0.5`**. Obviously for each index `i`, there'll be a minimum 1 element (self similarity is 1.0) and can be a maximum of `N` elements (`similarities` is `NxN` matrix with the diagonal elements as 1

Comment: Update your question with an expected result for a toy problem. Make `m=5` or something like that and compute it by hand. I'm still not sure what _format_ you want the output to have. Is it the output the matrix?